# Workaround for unsupported printers in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers, printer

My mother's old beloved printer is not supported in Windows 8 so it no longer works. Now what to do?

(using Linux, OSX or any other OS is not an option - buying a new printer is the last)

I was thinking that I might could connect the printer to a router for wireless printing, but then I discovered that the driver still has to be install on the PC.

UPDATE
The printer is OKI 3450 and the vendor has an official document where it is stated that it is not supported. I would however like the solution to the problem to be general and not specific for any product...

UPDATE
She gave up.. got a new printer...

Comment: Which printer is it? Many "not supported" printrs can in fact be used quite easily.

Comment: For Automated Installation: Normally printers with LCD control panels lets you configure the wireless connection directly from them. The printer will detect networks within range then you can select your network and enter the password, and you're good to go. For Manual installation, your printer's installation software will take care of the IP address and firewall settings. However, if you have to install a printer manually, its sure a pretty long process.

Comment: @EugenRieck The printer is OKI 3450

Comment: @vembutech thank you but this printer dont have a fancy LCD. It makes nice prints though

Comment: I don't know if this will be useful for an Okidata printer, but for brands like HP that have huge "families" of printers, there will often be a model that is similar and it has a compatible driver.  You can sometimes use the other printer's driver.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has stated that there is no longer a problem to solve (and solutions cannot be tested).

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to install the driver in compatibility mode. Right click on the setup file and go to the compatibility tab. You can then select to install it in Windows 7 or XP mode. This doesn't always work, but it's worth a shot.

This may be a stupid question, but have you checked the printer manufacturer's website for a current Windows 8 driver?

Comment: I did check the website and it was there I found that it is not supported. I tried to install it anyway (of course) and were confirmed that it didn't work.

Comment: Did you attempt to install in compatibility mode?